# Is there a conditional lower bound for the k max subarray sum problem?

Tags: ds.algorithms, lower-bounds

Consider an array $A$ of integers of length $n$.  The $k$-max subarray sum asks us to find up to $k$ (contiguous) non-overlapping subarrays of $A$ with maximum sum.  If $A$ is all negative then this sum will be $0$. If $A = [-1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, 2]$ for example, then the two subarrays could be $[2, -1, 2]$ and $[2, 2]$ with total sum $7$.

This problem can be solved in $O(nk)$ time by a small extension of [Kadane's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem).  I am interested to know if it can be solved faster or if there is a conditional lower bound that implies this might be essentially tight.

One reason the complexity can't be exactly tight is that if $k=n$ we can simply find all the positive numbers in the array in linear time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [*"Computing Maximum-Scoring Segments Optimally"*](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C22&q=%22Computing+Maximum-Scoring+Segments+Optimally%22&btnG=) by Fredrik Bengtsson & Jingsen Chen the authors describe an $O(n)$ algorithm.

Comment: That link takes me to "Credit risk modelling and prediction: Logistic regression versus machine learning boosting algorithms"

Comment: I edited to replace the link (with https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C22&q=%22Computing+Maximum-Scoring+Segments+Optimally%22&btnG=)

Comment: @NealYoung there must be a problem as that just adds another step before the wrong link.

Comment: Odd.  Try following the "All 3 versions" link at the google scholar page.  This will take to https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=17449434977220360777&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22, which  gives several different sources.  Do they all fail for you?  They work for me.

Comment: @NealYoung It must have been my phone browser (chrome) I tried a different browser and it works. Thank you.

Comment: @Simd Odd, the link worked for me from the start.